# How are rewrite rules applied in WordPress?

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect

How are rewrite rules applied in WordPress? I don't see any rules in the .htaccess file...

For example, if I set the address URL to www.example.com, then calls to example.com will 301 redirect to www.example.com, but I don't see any rule for that in the .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: All the rewrite rules are stored in the database.

Comment: I'm asking about how the rules are applied, not where they're stored.

Answer (score 1):

`index.php` acts as a router. All requests are sent through index.php which looks up the rules in the database and directs you to the correct location. [This](http://bit.ly/rRe3Y6) should give you an idea of how a PHP router works. The `.htaccess` just removes index.php from the URL. More rules can be created using the `WP_Rewrite` class.

Answer (score 0):

**When Your index.php is loaded wordpress askes for your "website url"

That adress is preDefined in your database.**

**As for posts and pages** in the case you are using pretty links meanina
a custom permalink structure & in the case you have changed the url
after initial draft is saved wordpress uses a 301 permenent redirect.

**If you are asking from an seo point of view** you should know the your Base URL
is the one you have set in your admin meaning:
settings >> general >> WordPress address (URL)

So... (from an seo point of view) you should take a moment to set
up the preffered address in google webmaster tool in order to keep
all your link juice directed to the right place since technicily speaking
 somewebsite.com & www.somewebsite.com are 2 different addresses.